# Duplicate results in mysql query when try to sort on null field by with limit and offset

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am trying to sort data with nullable field and also trying to achieve pagination using limit and offset

Here is query for first page

```
SELECT table_name.* FROM table_name ORDER BY table_name.date_field DESC LIMIT 2;
```

and I get following result.

| id | field1 | field2 | date_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | name | null |
| 2 | name1 | name1 | null |

while following query being used for second page

```
SELECT table_name.* FROM table_name ORDER BY table_name.date_field DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2;
```

and I get following result.

| id | field1 | field2 | date_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | name1 | name1 | null |
| 3 | name2 | name2 | null |

if you compare both table, you will notice that record with **id=2** given two times (in a first query and in a second query) which is wrong.

This is simple query with no join and with no where condition.

Does anybody has solution? thanks in advance.

I am using mysql version : 8.0.34 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: No null value is greater or less than any other null value, so ordering by null values produces arbitrary results, not wrong results. If you want deterministic ordering, use deterministic values for that.

Comment: @mustaccio but this issue happens only on server but in local mysql, its working fine, how can it is possible, so I am looking for configuration for mysql if any which is related to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on mustaccio's comment, the database isn't doing anything wrong, rather the issue you're running into is called [nondeterministic sorting](https://blog.kalvad.com/sql-paging-requires-a-deterministic-sort-order-a-classic-example-of-s-e-p-somebody-elses-problem/). It is a flaw in your logic.

Simply speaking, nondeterministic sorting is when an `ORDER BY` clause is used with non-unique values (in your cases a bunch of `NULL`s). When asked to sort the same value between multiple rows, there is no right or wrong way to sort them, and repeated runs of the same query may return different orders of those rows, making it nondeterministic (inable to be concretely determined repeatedly).

Picture this example for a moment: There are 10 pairs of socks, all colored red, and each pair has a unique number on them. Someone tells you to sort them by **color** and then hand them the first 2 pairs of socks. What order do you put the socks in? Furthermore, that person puts those 2 pairs of socks back in the pile and then asks someone else to sort them by **color** again and hand them the last 2 pairs of socks. Since they're all the same color, there is no reliably repeatable way to sort the socks by **color**, again and again, and it's entirely possible that the person receives the same exact pairs of socks both times (despite asking for the *first* and *last* pairs).

> this issue happens only on server but in local mysql, its working fine, how can it is possible...

It is a *coincidence* that it's working on your local MySQL instance, but any time you run the query it can potentially turn into a problem. The sorting on non-unique values means there's no guarantee, regardless of what past results you saw.

> so I am looking for configuration for mysql if any which is related to this issue?

There is no such configuration for this. This is a logical flaw in your design, and exists in all database systems and in life in general as per my example about socks demonstrates.

To fix your issue, you need to add a field to the `ORDER BY` clause that makes the entire expression unique. One example could be if you added the `id` field like so:

```
SELECT table_name.* 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY 
    table_name.date_field DESC,
    table_name.id DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

This would still follow your logic of sorting by the `date_field`, but when there's a tie between non-unique dates (e.g. `NULL`s), it then falls back to the `id` to be the consistent tie-breaker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am agree with your answer but In my local server, I notice that it automatically sort record by id in background which is the reason, its working in local but same thing is not happen on server. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @RohitRamani I understand, and as I said that is a *coincidence*. It won't always do that, despite what you're currently seeing. There is no option to have it automatically sort by the `id` without explicitly listing it in your code. You are essentially just getting *lucky* that you're getting the results you want but it's not guaranteed and will one day return the results not how you want even on your local server. There's a lot of complexities in the database engine that affect the order of the final results, and because of that it is a rule that it's not guaranteed without explicit sorting.

Comment: Thanks , this will help everyone to educate issue.

Comment: @RohitRamani Absolutely, no problem! Best of luck!